# Get response from .post() to PHP file but only within the MVC

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, validation

My JavaScript file contains this code:

```
$.post('./admin/test.php', {
        todoID:todoID
    }, function(data){
        $("."+todoID).html(data);           
    });
```

And my PHP file, from which I should get the response, contains this:

```
  if (!defined(__ACCESS)) {
     die("Access Denied!");
  }  

  echo '<span><input type="button" value="Edit" /></span>
  <span><input type="button" value="View" /></span>
  <span><input type="button" value="Delete" /></span>';
```

Of course the response that I get is "Access Denied!".

Because `__ACCESS` is defined in the index.php, and that is because I do not want someone to be able to run any PHP script without being validated (if user ok, if he tries to call a script individually he gets access denied) first.

So is there a way to validate that call?

Comment: How is __ACCESS defined?

Comment: __ACCESS is defined in the index.php
     define('__ACCESS', "True");

This is only for the purpose so no one can call a php file outside of the MVC.
I understand that this might not be the best way to do it.
If you can point/tell me a better way, that would be nice.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't touch PHP code since a long time, but the general mechanism for this kind of thing is:

1. The users logs in into your web app. The server generates a session, and returns to the client a session id as a cookie.
2. Ajax calls preserves all the cookies, so when you do a POST your session id is sent again.
3. If the request has a valid (not expired) session id for the origin is considered authenticated.

Take a look into this other question: [how to implement php login or authentication session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590103/how-to-implement-php-login-or-authentication-session)

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix would be:

```
include 'index.php';
if (!defined(__ACCESS)) {
    die("Access Denied!");
}
```

A better fix would be using a proper authentication framework. Or even a framework in general.

Comment: Yes but in this case if someone will call the php file he will get the results that I do not want to have access to.
I am trying to do that within an MVC.
If you could direct me to information about how to make a proper authentication framework I would be grateful to you.

I am trying to learn PHP ok Im not a rookie but still I need a lot of work.

Thank you for your response!

Comment: @user1608184 http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2011/08/security-review-creating-secure-php.html